# Nest a Controller / URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I have an `Albums` Scaffold and the current `Show Action` URL of a given Album is:

```
http://localhost:3000/albums/Test
```

Hence **any** given album belongs to a user, i'm struggling on how to set up a nested linking (?) so the url would look something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/user/albums/Test
```

A while back when i did my *User Profile page* for *Devise Users* i changed the routes to this:

```rb
# User Profile
get "users/show"
get 'user/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
```

I tried to mimic this action for the Albums, but nothing.

**THE WHOLE IDEA IS:**

To leave the albums_path the same so the albums can be viewed from within `localhost:3000/albums`, just when an albums is opened (Show) then the url changes to localhost:3000/user/testuser/albums/albumname.

With this i'm trying to avoid the duplicates in the Album Names, as there will be a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
get ':user_id/albums/:name', :to => 'albums#show', :as => :album
```

to access it in the view, you would pass the following:

```
Check out my band's new <%= link_to @album.name, album_path(user_id: X, name: @album.name) %>
```

and in the url it would look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/2/albums/Music_for_Airports 
#note that the formatting for the album name could be tricky to get right!
```

Comment: Uhh, i didn't quite understand where the album_path goes. The formatting of the album name is currently via a def to_param :name, the same for the Users.

Comment: Oh i understood. But do i have to change every link in my app to this? Isn't there a way to automatically set a default for the Albums ?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand?  default for what?

Comment: For the Album url, hence an album can only be created by a user and Belongs_to a user, is it possible to set a default route so the album is after the user in the url. Localhost:3000/user/albums/name

Comment: ah i see - well you could use [namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) - but i think you're misunderstanding routing a bit.  the album can only belong to one user, but the application has many users, all with albums - so you need to define just what user it is you're talking about, and the route i showed you is the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: I think i understood the namespaces. I updated my Question, could you give it a look? Your route atm gives me a undefined method user_path.

Comment: sorry, i think you're just being lazy :/  you can't change the routes without changing the routing.  just use find and replace?  it won't take that long.

Comment: No no, don't get me wrong :) Nothing to do with laziness, i just didn't understood your approach :(.

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach to doing this. The thing that comes to my mind is something like this

```
resource :users do
  resources :albums
end
```

But that will still change your link_path param to `user_albums_path`.

Comment: Where do i have to change the link_path params, because simply changing it in the view files wont work :(